# Database notification using signalr and asp.net not displaying the data in UI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr-hub, signalr.client

i followed the tutorial to from one of the online blog and am able get the application out with out error, but main issue is its not giving error as well as output.

My hub class looks like this

```
  public void NotifyAllClients(string msg)
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>();
        context.Clients.All.displayNotification(msg);
    }

My ASPX.CS page looks like this

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendNotifications();
    }

    public void SendNotifications()
    {
        string message = string.Empty;
        string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDB"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
        {
            string query = "SELECT [Message] FROM [dbo].[MessageBuffer]";

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                command.Notification = null;
                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    message = reader[0].ToString();
                }
            }
        }
        NotificationsHub nHub = new NotificationsHub();
        nHub.NotifyAllClients(message);
    }

    private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
        {
            SendNotifications();
        }
    }
```

and My aspx page is --

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>


     <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.2.js"></script>
      <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var notify = $.connection.notificationsHub;

            notify.client.displayNotification = function (msg) {

                $('#newData').append('<li><strong>' + msg + '</li>');
            };

            $.connection.hub.start();
        });
    </script>



        <div style="padding:10px 0px 10px 10px">
New Messages:
              <ul id="newData"></ul>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

i have done different samples, i have used same format to display, i am able to get those out in a hand, but here i am stuck with this. i am getting value in aspx.cs page, it calling the DB, which i have given in global.asax. and i have added sqldependency as well, enbabled broker in DB. but issue is still there. i cant see anything in UI. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while back. I just used the hub method name attribute and it worked for me. So you want something like

```
[HubMethodName("SendNotifications")]
    public string SendNotifications()
```

And then at the front end just do

```
$.connection.hub.start(function () {
notify.server.SendNotifications();
});
```

**Update**

You could have a span the way I have in my code. so something like

```
<div>
<ul>
  <li>New Messages:<span id="newData">0</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Then do

```
$('#newData').text(msg);
```

Comment: Hi lzzy,, i tried your suggestion.. it dint do any good thing, i still have the same error. and do you want me add the [HubMethodName] to aspx.cs page methor or actual HubMethos.

Comment: Add it to the actual HubMethod

Comment: Just a side note have you got `app.MapSignalR();` in your `Startup.cs`?

Comment: Ya i have added, i ran in IE , i am able to reach the  hub proxy creation in aspx page, and i dint get any exception, can you see weather am displaying it proper or not?

Comment: No Error found, my instinct says notify.client.displayNotification = function (msg) {

                $('#newData').append('<li><strong>' + msg + '</li>');
            };

Comment: the way am calling the displayNotification is right ? i am not sure about this. can you have a look into that.

Comment: You're not closing the `<strong>` tag that's the first issue. You're calling the `displayNotification` correctly

Comment: See my updated answer. It's very similar to what I have in my code and it works perfectly.

Comment: Hi.. i tried that.. No Luck :( . can you please provide me your mail id . ill forward my code to you.